# Event Log practicality

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, logging, event-log

We currently have a custom logging system. Its a single dll that pushes logs to Microsoft SQL server. Those logs are viewed via a webpage, with advanced sorting/filtering/paging/download. I built the system from scratch and I was new to Entity Framework and am not super strong in SQL.

One co-worker is insisting that Windows Event Log is a better choice than the SQL server, as it would save on bandwidth, therefore being quicker. Also that it is a tried and true solution.

I am questioning the practicality of using Windows Event Log to handle our extensive logging. Currently in SQL we have a single Log table which hosts around 150 million logs received from ~100 different machines across ~600 applications is about 90gb total.

Is using Windows Event Log a viable solution for that kind of load? Then creating a way for an admin server/user to request/sort/filter/page those logs without an intermediary SQL? Or am I just blinded by due to having built the current system?

**Additional Info**

Log is a single table Log(Id, AppId, Type, Lvl, Source, Msg, Time)

150 million logs covers Errors for 7 days, everything else for 3 days

Normalizing Source and Msg would drastically reduce the size of the table as there are many duplicate messages.

Most complaints about the current system is that the webpage times out on certain applications when requesting logs. The timeout is still 30 seconds, logs are limited to 10,000 total, at that point you have to refine your search. The timeout really only occurs on applications which have an average of 800k+ logs. Other apps return results at an average max of 10 seconds.

I am making changes to indexes and have thought about normalizing the table to increase efficiency but its an ongoing process. If Windows Event Log is a better solution however I would rather spend my time implementing that.

Comment: I would recommend tweaking your solution, perhaps by partitioning the log table for performance.

Comment: If you can write to Windows Event Log locally (not going through the network) to "save bandwidth", then you could also [`Run SQL Server Without a Network`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187078.aspx) and also save bandwidth. I have a hunch that the Windows Event Log won't be able to handle ~300 million logs per week, and if it does I don't get how it would sort/fliter/etc.. faster than SQL. edit: just saw it's 100 machines, your coworker is suggesting you save logs to 100 different locations? Even if EventLog supports writing remotely, there's no way it handles it better than sql.

Comment: So 100 machines writing to their own event logs? How would you collate them?  If you ship logs to a central location how would that improve bandwidth? - The event log is not an optimised database and will not perform anywhere near as well as such.

Comment: A ready-made alternative would be [splunk](http://www.splunk.com/).

Comment: @AxelKemper - Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately due to the type of information that can be found in the logs my company refuses to allow that data to leave the building.

Comment: @Zholen: splunk allows you to keep your data internal. You setup your own server which collects the data. Nothing is sent elsewhere. The advantage is that indexing is extremely fast and the entitled users can evaluate the collected data in a very flexible manner. You can also start predefined scripts or alerts if certain logging patterns are detected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***This is my sole own opinion***

Windows event logging for distributed systems is a bad idea.

Your idea of centralizing your logs for your applications is great. This will help you do statistics, you have a backup mechanism, you can use sql server for clustering, etc.

If people complain about performance issues, maybe it would be time to look into optimizing your solution. Indices maybe? Look at what could be indexed. Make sure SQL Server can make use of your search arguments (SARGS) when using WHERE conditions.

Can you split your data into multiple tables? Maybe normalizing your data should be looked into.

You could also look into pre-made filters that your users use and make them available and work on them (performance)

This is just a start. There's probably details we don't know and that you can't disclose